# Moving Germany from Belgium

Tags: germany, pakistani-citizens, belgium, refugees

i am a Pakistani living in Belgium from last 2 year do I have submitted application for asylum in Belgium and now I have won my asylum case and I got refugee status and I have refugee permit validity of 5 years with UN passport do I want to ask to you can I move to Germany permanently I mean to say can I convert my paper in Germany

Comment: What do you mean by ‘convert my paper’? To move to Germany you’d need a visa (eg work visa, job seeker visa) if you are eligible https://www.germany-visa.org/immigration-germany/

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

You have been granted asylum in Belgium which means you aren't eligible to asylum in Germany any more.

You can't legally move to Germany because you aren't eligible to a German *Aufenthaltsberechtigung* either, if this isn't a case of family reunion. The latter only applies to father, mother and their own childs, not other members of a greater family.